# Is it possible to define the execution order in Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, synchronization, parallel.for

```
// parameters.Count == 10
// actualFreeLicenses == 2
Parallel.For(0, parameters.Count, new ParallelOptions() 
                    {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = actualFreeLicenses
                    }, i =>
                    {
                        ExternalProgram(i);
                    }
);
```

When I execute the above code I notice that the value of `i` passed to the `ExternalProgram` method are 1 & 6, later 2 & 7, later 3 & 8 ...

If I have 14 Parameters and 2 licenses it always launch 1 & 8, later 2 & 9 ...

Is it possible to define order: first 1 & 2, later 3 & 4 etc?

Comment: You need to use continuations if you have order dependencies.

Comment: @Sven It's not necessary but will be useful - here it would be offtopic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Parallel the order in which they are executed is not of relevance therefore "Parallel". You should use a sequential workflow if the order is relevant for you.

Comment: ExternalProgram(i) take a lot of time so I need multithreading. Sometimes I have more free licenses. And sequence is not necessary but will be useful

Comment: @Saint, and cant you use `Task` with [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) to run some sequences after thread has done its work?

Comment: You could use a Queue for the sequence of the Items, and multiple threads which are requesting their Items from this Queue. So you could decide how may threads and in which order. Please don't forget to Lock the access to the Queues.

Comment: @oberfreak: ... or use ConcurrentQueue

Answer (score 12):

How about using a Queue/ConcurrentQueue and dequeueing items in the body of your parallel loop? This will ensure that ordering is preserved.

Comment: Sorry, saw your answer after commenting... Sorry for that! +1 for it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you *might* want to use `Parallel.ForEach` with a [custom partitioner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx) instead - but don't forget that it's not really doing "1 & 6, then 2 & 7" - it's doing (say) 1 on thread 1, 6 on thread 2, then 7 on thread 2, etc. It's not launching *pairs* of processes as such.

If you want to launch groups of processes, you should probably perform the grouping yourself, then loop over those groups *in series*, only providing the parallelism *within the group*, by specifying a maximum degree of parallelization equal to the group size.

Answer (score 1):

If you could switch to using a [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991604.aspx) (after having generated a range of numbers, perhaps, using [`IEnumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)), you could use one of the overloads that takes a [`Partitioner<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381768.aspx). That third link includes a sample partitioner that provides a single element at a time.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the runtime is looking at how many threads you want to use and dividing the workload up into that. e.g. the first thread is working on the first half of the dataset and the second thread is working on the second half of the data.